# Long running WCF in shared hosting

Tags: multithreading, wcf, hosting

I have a WCF (on top of IIS) which will be hosted on a shared hosting environment, so I don't have access to window services or permissions for installations.
This WCF would have a long running computation (it is a spatial interpolation), so my question is about which architecture to use in order to not affect performance, in particular I don't want to grab threads from the ASP.NET tread pool for such long task.
I know that a possible solution would be a window service for multi-threading computation and MSMQ for communicating between the WCf and the window service, but as I said I don't have the possibility to install a service.
Anybody could suggest a solution?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could simple use an asynchronous/one-way method on your WCF service and call this.

We use a similar method to upload data and kick off the import process. The client will then poll using another WCF method and when the initial process has finished, update the relevant data to indicate that and return it back to the client in the poll.

Comment: Do you mean that if I use an asynchronous/one-way method the thread for the long task would be grabbed from I/O threads and this wouldn't affect the thread pool of IIS? In this case I would like to know what happens with the concurrency of such method, is it reliable in case of many requests? Another question is whether the method of WCf would be prone to recycle of IIS app pools or not, I mean if the app pool gets recycled for some reason the thread responsible of the long task would be lost?Thanks in advance ChrisBint